# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am putting together a small Todo list app in node and I am getting the error above.  I am also using ejs as a template. My app.js file looks like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 //const request = require('request');
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js")

//console.log(date());
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

const listItems = ['cooking', 'shopping', 'watch TV', 'go to the gym'];
const workItems = []

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){

 const day = date.getDate();

 res.render("list", { listTitle: day, items: listItems });

 });

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  //post items
 const item = req.body.newItem;
 if (req.body.list === "Work") {
  workItems.push(item)
  res.redirect("/work")
  } else {
 listItems.push(item);
 res.redirect("/")
 }

//
 listItems.push(item);
 res.redirect("/")

})

app.get('/work', function(req, res){

res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", items: workItems});

});

app.post('/work', function(req, res){
//post items
 let item = req.body.newItem;
 workItems.push(item)
 res.redirect("/work")
 })

 app.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
 });
```

When I add an item it seems to work Ok but this is what I have in the console and I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this section, you are calling `res.redirect("/")` outside of `ifelse` and this is generating the error, because `res.redirect()` will be called if it is true or false and soon after these conditions it was called again. And you can not set the header after it is sent.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
//post items
    const item = req.body.newItem;
    if (req.body.list === "Work") {
        workItems.push(item)
        res.redirect("/work")
    } else {
        listItems.push(item);
        res.redirect("/")
    }//
    listItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

You have to work to review your logic or maybe it is the case that you use switch in this snippet of code.

Comment: Will check this out later. Thanks for replying Anderson.